# How to show $G$ is a perfect set that contains no rational points?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

For $E:=[0,1]$, since $\Bbb Q\cap E$ is enumerable, let it be $\{q_1,q_2,\cdots\}$. If I remove the elements of $V_1:=(q_1-\frac1{10},q_1+\frac1{10})$ from $E$, I obtain a closed (and compact) set $G_1:=E-V_1$ (E doesn't necessarily contain $V_1$, though). Similarly, if I remove the elements of $V_2:=(q_2-\frac{1}{10^2},q_2+\frac{1}{10^2})$, I obtain $G_2:=E-V_2$...and so forth. I propose to show that $G:=\bigcap_{i\in\Bbb N}G_i$ is a required perfect set, but I get stuck in the following steps:

1). First, I have some difficulty in showing that $G$ is nonempty. Although somebody has told me that $\mu(G)>0\implies G $ is uncountable, I do not want to involve measure theory here since it is currently too advanced for me to use. It is intuitively easy to see that $G$ must be nonempty, since the total length of $\{V_i\}_{i\in\Bbb N}$ is $\frac49<1$. However, I do not really know how to prove this point *rigorously* using only the properties of Euclidean space.

2). Second, I don't know how to show that $G$ contains no isolated points. I don't know what contradiction to induce if there should exist one.

Can you help me with this? I'll be especially grateful to a proof based on basic topology of the Euclidean metric space, thanks in advance!

---

EDIT. This is not a dupe. My example is not based on Cantor set as in previous questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have does *not* contain any non-trivial interval. If $0\le a<b\le 1$, there is some $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ such that $q_n\in(a,b)\subseteq[a,b]$, so clearly $[a,b]\nsubseteq G$.

Whether $G$ contains any isolated points depends on exactly how $[0,1]\cap\Bbb Q$ is enumerated; I’ll sketch the construction of a $G$ that has an isolated point. Before doing so, though, let me note that if your $G$ does *not* have any isolated points, then in fact it *is* a Cantor set.

**Corrected.** Let

$$\alpha=0.10100100010\ldots=\sum_{k\ge 1}\frac1{10^{k(k+1)/2}}\;;$$

$\alpha$ is clearly irrational. Let $q_1=0$, and for $n\ge 2$ let

$$q_{n(n+1)}=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac1{10^{k(k+1)/2}}\;,$$

so that $q_3=0.1$, $q_{6}=0.101$, $q_{10}=0.101001$, and so on. (These are the rational numbers obtained by truncating the decimal expansion of $\alpha$ after each $1$.) Observe that

$$V_{n(n+1)/2}=\left(q_{n(n+1)/2}-\frac1{10^{n(n+1)/2}},\,q_{n(n+1)/2}+\frac1{10^{n(n+1)/2}}\right)$$

and that

$$q_{(n+1)(n+2)/2}=q_{n(n+1)/2}+\frac1{10^{n(n+1)/2}}\;,$$

the righthand endpoint of $V_{n(n+1)/2}$, so it’s not hard to see that

$$\bigcup_{n\ge 1}V_{n(n+1)/2}=[0,\alpha)\;.$$

Now let $M$ be the set of positive integers not of the form $n(n+1)/2$, and let $Q$ be the set of rational numbers in $[0,1]$ not belonging to the set $\{q_{n(n+1)/2}:n\in\Bbb Z^+\}$. Suppose that we have a bijection $\varphi:M\to Q$ such that $\alpha\notin V_{\varphi(m)}$ for each $m\in M$. Then $\alpha\in G$, and $\alpha$ is isolated from the left in $G$. Is there such a bijection?

Enumerate $Q=\{p_n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\}$, and enumerate $M=\{m_k:k\in\Bbb Z^+\}$ so that $m_k<m_\ell$ whenever $k<\ell$. Let $\varphi(m_1)=p_n$, where $n$ is the smallest positive integer such that $|p_n-\alpha|\ge 2\cdot10^{-m_1}$. If $\varphi(m_k)$ has been defined for $k<\ell$, let $\varphi(m_\ell)=p_n$, where $n$ is the smallest positive integer such that $|p_n-\alpha|\ge 2\cdot10^{-m_1}$, and $p_n\notin\{\varphi(m_k):k<\ell\}$. At stage there are infinitely many $p_n$ satisfying the conditions, so the recursive construction goes through to define an injection $\varphi:M\to Q$.

Suppose that $\varphi$ is not surjective. Let $n$ be minimal such that $p_n\notin\varphi[M]$, and let $\epsilon=\frac12|p_n-\alpha|$. Then there is a smallest positive integer $\ell$ such that $\varphi^{-1}(p_k)<m_\ell$ for each $k<n$ *and* $10^{-m_\ell}\le\epsilon$, and the construction of $\varphi$ would have set $\varphi(m_\ell)=p_n$. This contradiction shows that $\varphi$ is the desired bijection.

This example only makes $\alpha$ isolated from the left, but the same idea can be used to make $\alpha$ isolated, though the details are more than a bit tedious. In $Q$ one constructs a sequence converging strictly downward to $\alpha$ in much the same way that the sequence $\langle q_{n(n+1)/2}:n\in\Bbb Z^+\rangle$ converges upward to $\alpha$, subscripting it in such a way that the associated $V$ intervals overlap and have a union containing an interval of the form $(\alpha,q)$ for some rational $q>\alpha$. This will use another infinite set of positive integer indices but will leave infinitely many positive integers unused. One then constructs a bijection from the set of unused positive integers to the set of unused rational in $[0,1]$ in exactly the way I constructed $\varphi:M\to Q$, and the resulting $G$ will have $\alpha$ as an isolated point.

Comment: How is $$\bigcup_{n\ge 1}V_{n(n+1)-1}=[0,\alpha)\;$$ true? Isn't $\alpha=0.09000900\dots\in V_5=(0.09-0.00001,0.09+0.00001)$?

Comment: @Vim: Yes, the indexing is off; I’ll spend some time now seeing if I can fix it easily and either do so or delete it for the time being.

Comment: Maybe letting $q_{n(n+1)}=\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{9}{10^{k(k+1)}}$ can fix this?